# OpengGL ES vertex buffer

Tags: ipad, opengl-es

I have the fallowing situation using vertex buffers in OpenGL on iPad:
- render some objects with 30 FPS
- delete the objects and create new ones(kill all entities and spawn others)
- render the new objects

The FPS drops to 10 for few seconds and slowly recovers to 30. I used some timers and I saw that render time increases from 30ms to 100ms for few seconds. Update time is increasing only when loading new objects(one frame) and send to render time is constant. I think the problem is with vertex buffers caching. Is there a way to force caching instead of waiting for OpenGL to do so? Do you have other opinions about this problem?

Comment: Does anyone knows the memory limit for VBOs on PowerVR SXG 535? It also may be out of video memory problem with creating new VBOs before deleting the old ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible option would be to not destroy the objects and recreate them but rather update the data in them using `glBufferSubData()`.

This may still not solve the caching problem because you're still putting new data in the buffer but I think it is guaranteed to be faster than destroying and recreating the buffer.

With this change in place, another thing you can try is to play with the `usage` parameter of `glBufferData()` and change it to `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` or `GL_STREAM_DRAW`. these are supposed to give OpenGL a hint that the buffers are changing frequently and perhaps that will drive it to optimize the caching appropriately.

Comment: This is the preferred method, destroying and creating VBOs during rendering is not a good practice.